# $f(x)$ continuous and periodic, then $f$ is bounded and reach its extreme values

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, solution-verification, periodic-functions

I know that if $f$ has period $k$, then $f([0,k])$ is compact, since $[0,k]$ is compact. By the weristrass theorem, the function at this interval reaches its extreme values in the interval $[0,k]$. Now, suppose the max value at $[0,k]$ at $f(c) = d$ and suppose there is a point outside $e\in[0,k]$ such that $f(e)>d$. Then, since $f$ is periodic, I can find a point in $g\in [0,k]$ such that $f(g) = e$, but since $d$ is the max value of $f[0,k]$, we have a contradiction, then $d$ must be the max, so $f$ is bounded everywhere by its maximum value.

Is my proof right?

Comment: Your proof is fine. You could also note that $f(\mathbb{R}) = f([0,k])$, and since $f$ is continuous, $f([0,k])$ is compact (hence bounded) and $f$ reaches its extrema in $[0,k]$.

Comment: I think you meant to say you can find a $g$ such that $f(g)=f(e)$ not $f(g)=e$

Comment: Also, I think you want to say $e \not\in [0,k]$.

Comment: it seems fine for me too